# Why does shouldStartLoadWithRequest not load my /amp version in the webview, and does in safari?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, webview, uiwebview

I have an iOS app with a `UIWebView` in it.
In my webiste all my pages have an /amp version in it `( i.e www.website-example.com/pageX/amp )`

In the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` method I do :`url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"amp"]`

if I do `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];return false;` (so it opens the url in Safari) it opens the good /amp version.

Otherwise, if I `return false` (after appending ***/amp***), it opens the url in the webview, it doesn't open the /amp version, although the URL contains /amp.

***edit:*** I'm adding Swift tag, because it's not a *programming language* problem, it's understanding shouldStartLoadWithRequest method.

What is the problem?

Comment: Please paste some related code.

Comment: added all necessary code

Comment: Why nobody answers? no one knows any answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can't append `/amp` to the url in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`, `/amp` must be added and passed to the `loadRequest` method. It opens fine in safari because you are passing "good" url, but UIWebView is opening url before appending `/amp`, and in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` you can't manipulate url.

Comment: hey, thank you for this answer. So what would be the way to do what I want?

Comment: Please edit question and paste code where is `loadRequest` called

Answer (score -1):

You should get this code :

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/amp", request.URL]]];
```

in the method :

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

That would be help you .

Comment: thanks, but could you please explain why and where should I add this? it doesn't work. and it gives a warning - requestWithURL takes an URL, not a string.

Comment: In this method `shouldStartLoadWithRequest `, load this method `[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/amp", request.URL]]]];`

Comment: This method ` [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];` always opens in safari.

Comment: The question is why in Safari it opens the /amp and in the webview-without? are u sure you understood this? Did you check your code? Thanks for trying to help anyway